# Angular Reactive Form Array with Radio Buttons

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-formbuilder

i have problems with reactive forms and an array of radio buttons.

My Form looks like this:

[image: Example]

There is a player in a row and i have to choose the status.

component:

```
 <tr *ngFor="let data of player">
        <th>{{data.firstname}} {{data.lastname}}</th>
        <th *ngFor="let stat of status">
        <input type="radio" id="opt1+{{data.id}}" value="{{stat}}" name="option+{{data.id}}" formArrayName="status???"></th>
      </tr>
```

The player data comes from an API and status is an array.

ts:

```
this.myForm = formBuilder.group({
    status: this.formBuilder.array,
    })
```

My example does not work.
I need a json-file as result. (playername + status e.g. present)
I can't find a way to implement it. 
Any hints?

Comment: Hans, you has not a FormArray, your form has only two fields: playerName and status (and status can be one of the value:·present, missing, apologizes and unexcused). You use an array to show the radiobuttons but you only has ONE formName

Comment: I think I need a extra name for each row. Right?
But I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see that you want to control all the players.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe you can do it without using a form.

Basically have a html setup like this using ngModel to set the status:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>present</th>
    <th>missing</th>
    <th>apologizes</th>
    <th>unexcused</th>
  </tr>
  <tr *ngFor="let data of player">
    <th>{{data.firstname}} {{data.lastname}}</th>
    <th *ngFor="let stat of status">
      <input type="radio" id="opt1+{{data.id}}" [(ngModel)]="data.status" value="{{stat}}" name="option+{{data.id}}">
    </th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And a simple function to get the required data:

```
  getJsonResult() {
    alert(JSON.stringify(this.player.map(x => {
      return {
        playername: x.firstname + ' ' + x.lastname,
        status: x.status
      }
    })));
  }
```

Working sample on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d6mjrq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).

**UPDATE**

ReactiveForm way requires a bit more code. First there is a FormGroup and then inside a FormArray with players. `formArrayName="players"`

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" [formGroup]="playersForm">
  <table border="1">
    <tr>
      <th>Firstname</th>
      <th>present</th>
      <th>missing</th>
      <th>apologizes</th>
      <th>unexcused</th>
    </tr>
    <tr formArrayName="players" *ngFor="let data of playersForm.get('players').controls; let i = index">
      <ng-container [formGroupName]="i">
        <th>
          <input type="text" formControlName="name" readonly>
        </th>
        <th *ngFor="let stat of status">
          <input type="radio" formControlName="status" value="{{stat}}">
        </th>
      </ng-container>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <br>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Typescript part will construct and fill the array.

`playersForm: FormGroup;`
`constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }`

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.playersForm = this.fb.group({
      players: this.fb.array([])
    });

    this.player.forEach(p => {
      (this.playersForm.get('players') as FormArray).push(
        this.addPlayerFormGroup(p.firstname + ' ' + p.lastname, '')
      );
    });
  }

  private addPlayerFormGroup(name?: string, status?: string): FormGroup {
    return this.fb.group({
      name,
      status
    });
  }

  onSubmit() {
    alert(JSON.stringify(this.playersForm.value));
  }
```

In app.moudule.ts
`import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';` instead of FormsModule.

New working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kqz6hj).

**UPDATE 2nd**

As @Eliseo suggested you can do it without nesting the FormArray.

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.playersForm = this.fb.array([]);

    this.player.forEach(p => {
      this.playersForm.push(
        this.addPlayerFormGroup(p.firstname + ' ' + p.lastname, '')
      );
    });
  }
```

html:

```
<tr *ngFor="let fg of playersForm.controls; index as i">        
<td>
  <input type="text" [formControl]="fg.get('name')" readonly>
</td>
<td *ngFor="let stat of status">

  <input type="radio" id="opt1+{{player[i].id}}" value="{{stat}}" name="option+{{player[i].id}}" 
    [formControl]="fg.get('status')">
</td>
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7u6kne)

**UPDATE 3rd**

If you have data from an observable consider the following approach. I'm using a SWAPI to get some data. Once you receive data. You can map raw data to the required format and then call a method to populate the FormArray.

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.playersForm = this.fb.array([]);
    let counter = 0;
    const apiUrl = 'https://swapi.co/api/people';    
    this.http.get(apiUrl).subscribe((peoples: any) => {
      this.player = peoples.results.map(p => {
        return {
          id: ++counter,
          name: p.name,
          staus: null
        }
      })
      this.populateForm();
    });
  }

  private populateForm() {
    this.player.forEach(p => {
      this.playersForm.push(
        this.addPlayerFormGroup(p.name, '')
      );
    });
  }
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7ur3vh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: I need more help. Currently the playersForm has only the fb.array. How can I add more fields? e.g. I need a teamname and year data field. Is formBuilder.group an option?

Comment: @HansPeter If you need more fields beside players check the first UPDATE there you have `this.playersForm = this.fb.group({...` as a main parent group inside that formGroup you can add more fields including the form array for the players etc.

Comment: OMG THANK YOU @robert for this comprehensive answer. 
I had to make some minor changes to the code under *Update* (1st one), here is my stackblistz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5hb1gh?file=src/app/app.component.html  
Specifically, I had to change the value of the input element to get the formControlName to stick and allow choosing a single radio per question (player).